# Why does running multiple scrapy spiders through CrawlerProcess cause the spider_idle signal to fail?

Tags: scrapy

I need to make thousands of requests that require a session token for authorization.

Queuing all the requests at once results in thousands of requests failing because the session token expires before the later requests are issued.

So, I am issuing a reasonable number of requests that will reliably complete before the session token expires.

When a batch of requests completes, the spider_idle signal is triggered.

If further requests are needed, the signal handler requests a new session token be used with the next batch of requests.

This works when running one spider normally, or one spider through CrawlerProcess.

However, the spider_idle signal fails with multiple spiders run through CrawlerProcess.

One spider will execute the spider_idle signal as expected, but the others fail with this exception:

```
2019-06-14 10:41:22 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.spider_idle of <SpideIdleTest None at 0x7f514b33c550>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/loren/.virtualenv/spider_idle_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 30, in send_catch_log
    *arguments, **named)
  File "/home/loren/.virtualenv/spider_idle_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "fails_with_multiple_spiders.py", line 25, in spider_idle
    spider)
  File "/home/loren/.virtualenv/spider_idle_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 209, in crawl
    "Spider %r not opened when crawling: %s" % (spider.name, request)
```

I created a repo that shows the spider_idle behaving as expected with a single spider, and failing with multiple spiders.

https://github.com/loren-magnuson/scrapy_spider_idle_test

Here is the version that shows the failures:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request, signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher


class SpiderIdleTest(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)
        self.idle_retries = 0

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        self.idle_retries += 1
        if self.idle_retries < 3:
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(
                Request('https://www.google.com',
                        self.parse,
                        dont_filter=True),
                spider)
            raise DontCloseSpider("Stayin' alive")

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request('https://www.google.com', self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.css('title::text').extract_first())


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(SpiderIdleTest)
process.crawl(SpiderIdleTest)
process.crawl(SpiderIdleTest)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running multiple spiders concurrently using billiard as an alternative approach.

After getting the spiders running concurrently using billiard's Process, the spider_idle signal still failed, but with a different exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/louis_powersports/.virtualenv/spider_idle_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 30, in send_catch_log
    *arguments, **named)
  File "/home/louis_powersports/.virtualenv/spider_idle_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "test_with_billiard_process.py", line 25, in spider_idle
    self.crawler.engine.crawl(
AttributeError: 'SpiderIdleTest' object has no attribute 'crawler'
```

This lead me to try changing:

```
self.crawler.engine.crawl(
Request('https://www.google.com',
        self.parse,
        dont_filter=True),
spider)
```

to

```
spider.crawler.engine.crawl(
Request('https://www.google.com',
        self.parse,
        dont_filter=True),
spider)
```

which works.

Billiard is not necessary.  The original attempt based on Scrapy's documentation will work after making the change above.

Working version of original:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request, signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher


class SpiderIdleTest(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)
        self.idle_retries = 0

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        self.idle_retries += 1
        if self.idle_retries < 3:
            spider.crawler.engine.crawl(
                Request('https://www.google.com',
                        self.parse,
                        dont_filter=True),
                spider)
            raise DontCloseSpider("Stayin' alive")

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request('https://www.google.com', self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.css('title::text').extract_first())


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(SpiderIdleTest)
process.crawl(SpiderIdleTest)
process.crawl(SpiderIdleTest)
process.start()
```